# command to get sha256 hash of certificate chain

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, sha256, sha

I got my server certificate `mycert.pem` . 
I would like to see the certificate chain hash value.

My question is:

How can I use command line to get the **SHA256 hash** of **certificate chain**?